# how to create Filtered index in stored procedure (SQL Server)

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm trying to create a filtered index using the stored procedure. However no error shows when the code is written in the stored procedure but when I run the query it cannot detect the FirstName parameter.

FirstName from BorrowerPersonal table

CardNumber from BorrowerCard table

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[BorrowerCardG11Match] 

@CardNo VARCHAR(20),
@FirstName VARCHAR(30)

AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(Max)
SET @CardNo = 17522
SET @FirstName = 'Simon'

        SET @SQL = N'SELECT dbo.BorrowerCard.BorrowerCardID
            FROM   dbo.BorrowerCard 
            INNER JOIN dbo.BorrowerPersonal
            ON dbo.BorrowerPersonal.BorrowerPersonalID = BorrowerCard.BorrowerPersonalID
            WHERE  CardNumber =' + CAST(@CardNo AS VARCHAR(20))
             SET @SQL += 'AND NameFirst = ' + CAST(@FirstName AS VARCHAR(30))

                   EXECUTE sys.sp_executesql @SQL   
END
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to have anything to do with creating filtered indexes...

Comment: Is there some reason to use dynamic SQL that's not in the question? As is this is a prime example of a scenario where you should use static SQL. As written, this procedure is a SQL injection attack waiting to happen.

Comment: If you ask questions containing code: Please do not change the code, as otherwise the answers become invalid. (You just tried to edit an answer so the code applies to your new question. This is not the way to do it. Just don't change your question!)

Comment: "I'll take SQL injection for $1000, Alex!"

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you don't have '' around the string in the SQL, but if you use sp_execute_sql you should actually just use the @FirstName variable in the SQL and add the value for the parameter separately. See examples: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx

Answer (score 2):

While existing answers (such as Giorgi Nakeuri's) show the way to make the dynamic SQL work, the question as stated has no reason to use dynamic SQL in the first place. Unless there's more to this procedure than has been presented, the best way to fix this would be to re-write it using static SQL:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[BorrowerCardG11Match] 

@No VARCHAR(20),
@First VARCHAR(30)

AS
BEGIN
SET @No = 17522
SET @First = 'Simon'

           SELECT dbo.Details.ID
            FROM   dbo.Details
            INNER JOIN dbo.Personal
            ON dbo.Personal.ID 
               = Details.ID
            WHERE  Number = @No
              AND  First = @Name

END
```

If you can't do that, you'd be better off binding the two variables you have, rather than concatenating them:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[BorrowerCardG11Match] 

@No VARCHAR(20),
@Name VARCHAR(30)

AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(Max)
DECLARE @SQLParams NVARCHAR(Max)
SET @No = 17522
SET @First = 'Simon'

        SET @SQL = N'SELECT dbo.Details.ID
            FROM   dbo.Details 
            INNER JOIN dbo.Personal
            ON dbo.Personal.ID 
               = Details.ID
            WHERE  Number = @No
              AND  Name = @First'
        SET @SQLParams = N'@No varchar(20), @First varchar(30)'

        EXECUTE sys.sp_executesql @SQL, SQLParams, 
                                  @No=@No, @Name=@Name   
END
```

These solutions prevent you from having to concatenate the single-quotes and protect against SQL injection attacks.

Answer (score -1):

You have several errors. This is what you will get with current statement.

```
SELECT dbo.Details.ID
            FROM   dbo.Details 
            INNER JOIN dbo.Personal
            ON dbo.Personal.ID = Details.ID
            WHERE  Number =17522AND Name = Simon
```

You can see it if you add `PRINT @SQL` before executing your query.

1. Add space before AND in `'AND Name ='`
2. Add additional quotes round Name

While the first is not a syntax error but bad formatting the second one actually is an error, because here it will be considered a column not a value 'Simon'.
Try this:

```
SET @SQL = N'SELECT dbo.Details.ID
        FROM   dbo.Details
        INNER JOIN dbo.Personal
        ON dbo.Personal.ID = Details.ID
        WHERE  Number =' + '''' + @No + '''' +
               ' AND Name = N' + '''' + @First + ''''
```

Comment: Dangerous. SQL injection.

Answer (score -1):

for `sql server 2012` you can use `concat`-

```
 set @SQL = concat('SELECT dbo.Details.ID
            FROM   dbo.Details 
            INNER JOIN dbo.Personal
            ON dbo.Personal.ID 
               = Details.ID
            WHERE  Number =''' ,@No,'''',' AND  Name = ''',@First,'''')
```

Comment: Dangerous. SQL injection.

Comment: please explain your answer?

Comment: Huh? I don't have an answer, because [Allan already gave a better one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28810191/61305).